# Reading crash logs in xCode

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a problem with reading crash logs in iOS. I developed an app then sent it to App store. Now sometimes I am getting crash reports. I want to fix these crashes but I couldn't read the log.

Where is the actual error messeage?

Here example log:

```
Incident Identifier: C487C965-E0E4-4A3D-BA14-783C52D66F30
CrashReporter Key:   3fd1b5c9adee705bf5adcf614156010c204e905b
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,4
Process:             Ribony [1674]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Ribony
Identifier:          com.impact.ribony
Version:             8 (1.0.8)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-09-18 18:27:49.49 +0300
Launch Time:         2015-09-18 13:35:33.33 +0300
OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B5110e)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x243f4876 __exceptionPreprocess + 122 (NSException.m:162)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36132dfa objc_exception_throw + 34 (objc-exception.mm:531)
2   Ribony                          0x1a2ede ___ZL17RLMAccessorGetterP11RLMPropertycP8NSString_block_invoke_8 + 210 (RLMAccessor.mm:35)
3   Ribony                          0x14920c @objc Ribony.FirstViewController.tableView (Ribony.FirstViewController)(ObjectiveC.UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath) -> ObjectiveC.UITableViewCell + 424 (FirstViewController.swift:410)
4   UIKit                           0x28a5ef0a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 674 (UITableView.m:10397)
5   UIKit                           0x28a5f030 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 64 (UITableView.m:10429)
6   UIKit                           0x28a4f2fa -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2126 (UITableView.m:2219)
7   UIKit                           0x28a63606 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 74 (UITableView.m:12150)
8   UIKit                           0x2881067a -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 174 (UITableView.m:7172)
9   UIKit                           0x287254ee -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 690 (UIView.m:11660)
10  QuartzCore                      0x27fedcf0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 124 (CALayer.mm:8822)
11  QuartzCore                      0x27fe93ec CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 348 (CALayer.mm:8702)
12  QuartzCore                      0x27fe927c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12 (CALayer.mm:2507)
13  QuartzCore                      0x27fe879c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 364 (CAContextInternal.mm:1627)
14  QuartzCore                      0x27fe844e CA::Transaction::commit() + 610 (CATransactionInternal.mm:417)
15  QuartzCore                      0x27fe1c0a CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 134 (CATransactionInternal.mm:764)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x243b70ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1620)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x243b53a2 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 278 (CFRunLoop.c:1716)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x243b57e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 968 (CFRunLoop.c:2558)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x24308124 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 512 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x24307f18 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
21  GraphicsServices                0x2d8cfaf4 GSEventRunModal + 156 (GSEvent.c:2245)
22  UIKit                           0x287909b8 UIApplicationMain + 140 (UIApplication.m:3660)
23  Ribony                          0xb6c20 main + 192 (AppDelegate.swift:12)
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x3688086e tlv_get_addr + 42 (threadLocalHelpers.s:310)

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
5.688441     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a1466c5 [0x173ce800] Releasing session
5.692965     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a14853d [0x173ce800] Decoding completed without errors
5.692965     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a146c31 [0x173ce800] Options: 128x128 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
5.692965     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a146afd [0x173ce800] Decoding: C0 0x00800080 0x0008304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 4661
5.694335     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a145fa1 [0x173ce800] Created session
5.785463     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a1466c5 [0x16bc0a00] Releasing session
5.791204     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a14853d [0x16bc0a00] Decoding completed without errors
5.791204     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a146c31 [0x16bc0a00] Options: 128x128 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
5.791204     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a146afd [0x16bc0a00] Decoding: C0 0x00800080 0x0008304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 5762
5.799717     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a145fa1 [0x16bc0a00] Created session
5.883665     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a1466c5 [0x173d0800] Releasing session
5.887650     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a14853d [0x173d0800] Decoding completed without errors
5.888699     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a146c31 [0x173d0800] Options: 128x128 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
5.888699     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a146afd [0x173d0800] Decoding: C0 0x00800080 0x0008304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 8085
5.891367     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a145fa1 [0x173d0800] Created session
5.937491     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a1466c5 [0x173ce800] Releasing session
5.940049     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a14853d [0x173ce800] Decoding completed without errors
5.942279     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a146c31 [0x173ce800] Options: 128x128 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
5.942279     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a146afd [0x173ce800] Decoding: C0 0x00800080 0x0008304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 9707
5.945534     AppleJPEG                  0x000000002a145fa1 [0x173ce800] Created session

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3694fc84 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369efb36 pthread_kill + 62 (pthread.c:1249)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x368e7f40 abort + 108 (abort.c:91)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x358fd7dc __cxa_bad_cast + 0 (cxa_aux_runtime.cpp:23)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x359166a0 default_unexpected_handler() + 0 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:81)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36133098 _objc_terminate() + 192 (objc-exception.mm:678)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35913e16 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78 (cxa_handlers.cpp:69)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x359138f6 0x358fd000 + 92406
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36132f46 objc_exception_rethrow + 42 (objc-exception.mm:582)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x243081ae CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 650 (CFRunLoop.c:2827)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x24307f1c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
11  GraphicsServices                0x2d8cfaf8 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2247)
12  UIKit                           0x287909bc UIApplicationMain + 144 (UIApplication.m:3663)
13  Ribony                          0x000b6c24 main + 196 (AppDelegate.swift:12)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x36880872 start + 2 (start_glue.s:66)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3693f4c0 kevent + 24
1   Ribony                          0x001d6d98 -[RLMNotifier listen] + 324 (RLMRealmUtil.mm:247)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36857e2e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10 (init.c:761)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x36863810 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1572 (inline_internal.h:1063)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x368631ea _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94 (queue.c:4250)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ece04 _pthread_wqthread + 1024 (pthread.c:1990)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ec9f4 start_wqthread + 8 (pthread_asm.s:151)

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36951320 kevent_qos + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x368679a6 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 254 (source.c:2545)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36859a86 0x36857000 + 10886

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3695088c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ece10 _pthread_wqthread + 1036 (pthread.c:1930)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ec9f4 start_wqthread + 8 (pthread_asm.s:151)

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3693bfbc mach_msg_trap + 20 (syscall_sw.h:105)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3693bdbc mach_msg + 40 (mach_msg.c:106)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x243b74ac __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136 (CFRunLoop.c:2345)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x243b5832 __CFRunLoopRun + 1050 (CFRunLoop.c:727)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x24308128 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x24307f1c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
6   Foundation                      0x2517eacc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 268 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
7   Ribony                          0x000c5ddc function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Owned To Guaranteed> of Ribony.WebSocket.(initStreamsWithData in _BFD745B6882B5565CCD0EA6B3BEF047D) (Ribony.WebSocket)(ObjectiveC.NSData, Swift.Int) -> () + 3180 (WebSocket.swift:263)
8   Ribony                          0x000c510c function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of Ribony.WebSocket.(createHTTPRequest in _BFD745B6882B5565CCD0EA6B3BEF047D) (Ribony.WebSocket)() -> () + 4764 (WebSocket.swift:206)
9   Ribony                          0x000cd208 partial apply forwarder for Ribony.WebSocket.(connect (Ribony.WebSocket) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) + 40 (WebSocket.swift:143)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x36857e2e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10 (init.c:761)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x36863810 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1572 (inline_internal.h:1063)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x368631ea _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94 (queue.c:4250)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ece04 _pthread_wqthread + 1024 (pthread.c:1990)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ec9f4 start_wqthread + 8 (pthread_asm.s:151)

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3693bfbc mach_msg_trap + 20 (syscall_sw.h:105)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3693bdbc mach_msg + 40 (mach_msg.c:106)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x243b74ac __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136 (CFRunLoop.c:2345)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x243b5832 __CFRunLoopRun + 1050 (CFRunLoop.c:727)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x24308128 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x24307f1c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
6   Foundation                      0x2517eacc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 268 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
7   Foundation                      0x251cd65c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80 (NSRunLoop.m:388)
8   Ribony                          0x00181d84 +[GAI threadMain:] + 64
9   Foundation                      0x2524f5ac __NSThread__start__ + 1144 (NSThread.m:1136)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369eec6e _pthread_body + 138 (pthread.c:656)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369eebe2 0x369ec000 + 11234
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369eca00 thread_start + 8 (pthread_asm.s:164)

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3693bfbc mach_msg_trap + 20 (syscall_sw.h:105)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3693bdbc mach_msg + 40 (mach_msg.c:106)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x243b74ac __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136 (CFRunLoop.c:2345)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x243b5832 __CFRunLoopRun + 1050 (CFRunLoop.c:727)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x24308128 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x24307f1c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
6   CFNetwork                       0x23c7701e +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 486 (NSURLConnection.mm:325)
7   Foundation                      0x2524f5ac __NSThread__start__ + 1144 (NSThread.m:1136)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369eec6e _pthread_body + 138 (pthread.c:656)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369eebe2 0x369ec000 + 11234
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369eca00 thread_start + 8 (pthread_asm.s:164)

Thread 7 name:
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3694ff14 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x243bc950 __CFSocketManager + 572 (CFSocket.c:2137)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369eec6e _pthread_body + 138 (pthread.c:656)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369eebe2 0x369ec000 + 11234
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369eca00 thread_start + 8 (pthread_asm.s:164)

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3695088c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ece10 _pthread_wqthread + 1036 (pthread.c:1930)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ec9f4 start_wqthread + 8 (pthread_asm.s:151)

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3695088c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ece10 _pthread_wqthread + 1036 (pthread.c:1930)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ec9f4 start_wqthread + 8 (pthread_asm.s:151)

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3695088c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ece10 _pthread_wqthread + 1036 (pthread.c:1930)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ec9f4 start_wqthread + 8 (pthread_asm.s:151)

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3695088c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ece10 _pthread_wqthread + 1036 (pthread.c:1930)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ec9f4 start_wqthread + 8 (pthread_asm.s:151)

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3695088c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ece10 _pthread_wqthread + 1036 (pthread.c:1930)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x369ec9f4 start_wqthread + 8 (pthread_asm.s:151)

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x368da8f5
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3977d000      r6: 0x39767314      r7: 0x004b54e8
    r8: 0x178475c0    r9: 0x359178fc     r10: 0xfb908d96     r11: 0x178475e4
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x004b54dc      lr: 0x369efb37      pc: 0x3694fc84
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0x5a000 - 0x2f9fff Ribony armv7  <411b01c0d63934889201b4ec56378de5> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Ribony
0x4b6000 - 0x4edfff Haneke armv7  <6f7d0196c0463cfdbbdb9932c1fbc3de> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Frameworks/Haneke.framework/Haneke
0x53a000 - 0x6a1fff libswiftCore.dylib armv7  <fa5b9494d6403f13ae80664a88301250> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x816000 - 0x821fff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib armv7  <95229d09c03d3eba9fbb038741503af3> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x836000 - 0x83dfff libswiftCoreImage.dylib armv7  <59ca6e9173993aa39882799efdafd355> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x84a000 - 0x851fff libswiftDarwin.dylib armv7  <764c0e157b49314088a4c9f8e1390a1a> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x862000 - 0x865fff libswiftDispatch.dylib armv7  <e167a8d29dfd3694b0db2d3fc60adbb0> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x872000 - 0x8a1fff libswiftFoundation.dylib armv7  <dde3f834069c3e6a9421572c0d01bbe3> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x8da000 - 0x8e1fff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib armv7  <786938b80ba63395aa5da6935df0c02e> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8A1AB6C7-3993-4D50-BCAB-8E61ACE34AAA/Ribony.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x8ee000 - 0x8f1fff libswiftSecurity.dylib armv7
```

**Line 410:**

```
cell.setCell(shufflePerson.name,bio: shufflePerson.bio,image: shufflePerson.image)
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I added line 410. It says "you have a problem at line 410" ok. But what is the problem? Is there any nil values? Or anything else? It doesn't say.

Comment: shufflePerson is a Realm object, right? Related issue found there https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1118

Comment: Yes, it is realm object.

Comment: It looks resolved on Github but I am already using latest version of Realm.